# What is the difference with find_by() from the core and the one from the FinderMethods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Currently I'm working on a gem, which overrides ActiveRecords `where`. By working on that, I stumbled on two different `find_by` implementations. One is in the [core](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-0-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/core.rb#L182) and it uses some kind of cache, whereas the one from the [`FinderMethods`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-0-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb#L77) module calls `where` directly. What is the difference between these two implementations? When is which used?

Comment: Perhaps it is just me, but overriding a Rails core method like `where` feels like a terrible idea to me...

Comment: Well, popular gems like `globalize` are doing that, too. Luckily  there are many tests for ActiveRecord..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's that way: When you use something like this:

```
User.find_by(...)
```

The `ActiveRecord::Core#find_by` is called, as the Core is included into Base from which you inherit.

But if you do something like:

```
User.first.products.find_by(...)
```

The ActiveRecord::Relation (includes `FinderMethods` [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c9061254de48437924293ef0e797365527107dc1/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L16)) will call `FinderMethods#find_by`

I don't know why this is implemented like that, but I'm sure there's a reason for this.