# How to override the where method of ActiveRecord properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I already successfully overrode the `where` method. The behavior I want to achieve is, if a my `hstore` is accessed, it rewrites the `where` query in such a way, that the `hstore` items are treated as separate columns. Here is my `where` method:

```
def where(opts = :chain, *rest)
  if opts == :chain
    WhereChain.new(spawn)
  elsif opts.blank?
    return self
  elsif opts.is_a?(Hash)
    translated_attributes(opts).each do |attribute|
      return spawn.where!("'#{opts[attribute]}' = any(avals(#{attribute}))", rest)
    end
  else
    super(opts, rest)
  end
end
```

For that I wrote this `minitest`, which works great!

```
def test_where_query_with_translated_value
  PageWithFallbacks.create!(:title_raw => {'en' => 'English title', 'de' => 'Deutscher Titel'})
  exp = PageWithFallbacks.create!(:title_raw => {'en' => 'Another English title', 'de' => 'Noch ein Deutscher Titel'})
  res = PageWithFallbacks.where(title: 'Another English title').first
  assert_equal(exp.id, res.id)
end
```

Now I wrote another test for the `find_by()` methods:

```
def test_find_by_query_with_translated_value
  PageWithFallbacks.create!(:title_raw => {'en' => 'English title', 'de' => 'Deutscher Titel'})
  exp = PageWithFallbacks.create!(:title_raw => {'en' => 'Another English title', 'de' => 'Noch ein Deutscher Titel'})
  res = PageWithFallbacks.find_by(title: 'Another English title')
  assert_equal(exp.id, res.id)
end
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. [As 'we' already found out there are two different implementation of `find_by()` in ActiveRecord.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511496/what-is-the-difference-with-find-by-from-the-core-and-the-one-from-the-finderm) `Find_by()` calls the implementation in the core, which creates a `ActiveRecord::StatementCache::Substitute` and hands this over to my `where` method. I don't know how to deal with this? How can I modify the statement?

By the way, this helps me to realize [awesome_hstore_translate](https://github.com/openscript/awesome_hstore_translate).